# Looking at the kernel logs to see if there is something wrong with my machine

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, pipe, fifo, slowdown

My ubuntu machine slowed down, I was following these instructions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/21632/slow-response-and-system-lag

the slowness I see is pretty uniform, and there's definitely a lot of delay when I click or type. sometimes I type 30 characters, and wait for them all to appear on the screen :(

this is what I see in the logs for `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`:

```
Mar 30 17:39:33 xps kernel: [ 2042.602201] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=122122 end=122123) time 183 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1068, end 1080 Mar 30 17:39:35 xps kernel: [ 2044.735890] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=122129 end=122130) time 265 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1062, end 1079 Mar 30 17:39:54 xps kernel: [
2063.685605] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=123387 end=123388) time 146 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1071, end 1080 Mar 30 17:40:14 xps kernel: [
2083.868953] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=124598 end=124599) time 237 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1068, end 1084 Mar 30 17:40:27 xps kernel: [
2096.985566] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=125385 end=125386) time 181 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1070, end 1081 Mar 30 17:40:35 xps kernel: [
2105.435562] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=125892 end=125893) time 157 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1071, end 1082 Mar 30 17:40:53 xps kernel: [
2123.402264] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=126970 end=126971) time 152 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1072, end 1082 Mar 30 17:40:55 xps kernel: [
2124.960538] perf: interrupt took too long (5190 > 5173), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 38500 Mar 30 17:41:12 xps kernel: [ 2141.818912] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=128075 end=128076) time 197 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1071, end 1083 Mar 30 17:41:59 xps kernel: [ 2189.352247] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=130927 end=130928) time 205 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1070, end 1083 Mar 30 17:42:08 xps kernel: [ 2198.085593] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe C (start=131451 end=131452) time 157 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1072, end 1082 Mar 30 17:42:11 xps kernel: [ 2200.541142] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=131467 end=131468) time 178 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1069, end 1081
```

anyone know if that's bad or good?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not good, it seems to be this bug:
[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806242](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1806242), 
[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813423](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1813423).
What's your Ubuntu release, kernel version and hardware? Switching to Wayland is an option or a kernel update might fix the issue if you're lucky.

Comment: this is what I have I guess: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/350b62e421c5d22ce4f1294986f25360

Comment: And then output of `uname -r` is: `4.15.0-91-generic`

Comment: Try a recent 5.3.x kernel and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Yeah I upgraded to ubuntu 19.10 which has `5.3.0-45-generic` kernel and it's so much better now lol thanks